# How to remove mouse hover effect from ListBox at AvaloniaUI?

Tags: .net, avalonia

How to remove mouse hover effect from ListBox at AvaloniaUI?

Here is my ListBox element:

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" x:Name="FileList" ItemsSource="{Binding FileInfoModels}" Tapped="FileList_OnTapped" DoubleTapped="FileList_OnDoubleTapped">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           
        </ListBox>
```

I tryed remove it via ListBox.Styles

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" x:Name="FileList" ItemsSource="{Binding FileInfoModels}" Tapped="FileList_OnTapped" DoubleTapped="FileList_OnDoubleTapped">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.Styles>
                <Style Selector="ListBoxItem:pointerover">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Styles>
        </ListBox>
```

but it still doestn work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to override the background of a `ContentPresenter` in the template instead

```
<Style Selector="ListBoxItem:selected /template/ ContentPresenter">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
</Style>
```

If you have similar problems you can look for the [associated xaml file](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Themes.Fluent/Controls/ListBoxItem.xaml) on Avalonia's github and see how the styles are applied there. Note that you have to find a file that corresponds to your library version and theme, because there are major differences between Avalonia 11 and earlier versions.

Comment: Thank you so much! Link to xaml file very helpfull. Many interesting thing to override

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't understand how/where to apply that style.

I have the following code:

```
 <Style Selector="ListBox.lstLanguages">
  <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
  <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then..

```
<ListBox Classes="lstLanguages" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SspLanguages}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Classes="pnlLanguages" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}">
        <Border Classes="brdFlag">
          <Svg Classes="imgFlag" Path="{Binding FlagPath}" />
        </Border>
        <Button Classes="btnLanguage" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
</ListBox>
```

I tried to add the style you said in my UserControl.Styles but didn't worked. What I'm mising?